# Does slicing a bytes object create a whole new copy of data in Python?

Tags: python, python-bytearray

Say I have very large bytes object (after loading binary file) and I want to read parts by parts and advance the starting position until it meets the end. I use slicing to accomplish this. I'm worried that python will create completely new copy each time I ask for a slice instead of simply giving me the address of the memory pointing to the position I want.

Simple example:

```py
data = Path("binary-file.dat").read_bytes()
total_length = len(data)
start_pos = 0

while start_pos < total_length:
   bytes_processed = decode_bytes(data[start_pos:])  # <---- ***
   start_pos += bytes_processed
```

In the above example does python creates completely new copy of bytes object starting from the `start_pos` due to the slicing. If so what is the best way to avoid data copy and use just a pointer to pass to the relevant position of the bytes array.

Comment: slices create new `bytes` objects. Now, it would be *possible* for python not to copy the underlying buffer, and share a buffer among slices. However, in general that is the case, and it will effectively copy the underlying buffer. Try this out yourself, `b = b'a'*1_000_000_000` should take about a gig of memory. Now interestingly, if you do a full copy, it doesn't seem to copy the underlying buffer, so `b2 = b[:]`, *however*, anything else, and it does, so `b3 = b[1:]`.

Comment: If you are working with `bytes` and you want a memory efficient way to slice them, use `memoryview` Note, *python doesn't have pointers*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks I'm from other programming languages, I thought pythin treat byte as a primitive type and hence possibly a copy (if it is a list with different object type it will still copy the references to new list as well) so this is not ideal in my case as I have to traverse through 12-20MB of data by 4000+ bytes per time, and have stream of such files, as you said memoryview could be the solution. Thanks

Comment: @jpnadas yes that gives some insight but I'm talking about bytes object, since it is immutable (where you cannot modify any element of the array) I thought slicing would not create new or copy references.

Comment: @Tekz it is important to understand, python *doesn't have primitive types*. Everything is an object. `bytes` are immutable, so it may or may not perform a copy of the underlying buffer. But python hasn't optimized for this, which it could (for example, `numpy` arrays do this, and `memoryiew` objects do this), apparently, except for the simply case of an empty slice, where it simply *returns the same bytes object*, i.e. `x = b"abcde"; print(x[:] is x)` will print `True`.

Comment: @Tekz that other question about lists is actually totally irrelevant here. `list` objects contain other python objects. A `bytes` object is essentially an object-oriented wrapper over a primitive buffer of bytes. Although it acts as a container, it doesn't actually *contain* other python objects, although, indexing returns python objects (ints, actually) and you can do membership testing with other `bytes` objects, but internally, there are no references to other python objects, just a primitive buffer of bytes, a char array basically.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I could have but actually I'm using 3rd party library for `decode_bytes` function so it accepts bytes only, im not sure `numpy.ndarray` can be passed directly

Answer (score 5):

Yes, slicing a bytes object does create a copy, at least as of CPython 3.9.12.  The closest the documentation comes to admitting this is [in the description of the `bytes` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> In addition to the literal forms, bytes objects can be created in a number of other ways:
>
> - A zero-filled bytes object of a specified length: `bytes(10)`
> - From an iterable of integers: `bytes(range(20))`
> - **Copying existing binary data via the buffer protocol: `bytes(obj)`**

which suggests *any* creation of a bytes object creates a separate copy of the data.  But since I had a hard time finding an explicit confirmation that slicing does the same, I resorted to an empirical test.

```
>>> b = b'\1' * 100_000_000
>>> qq = [b[1:] for _ in range(20)]
```

After executing the first line, memory usage of the `python3` process in `top` was about 100 MB.  The second executed after a considerable delay, making memory usage rise to the level of 2G.  This seems pretty conclusive.  PyPy 7.3.9 targetting Python 3.8 behaves largely the same; though of course, PyPy’s garbage collection is not as eager as CPython’s, so the memory is not freed as soon as the `bytes` objects become unreachable.

And it makes sense.  If slicing created a reference to the original buffer instead of copying it, you could create a memory leak by allocating a large `bytes` object, slicing one byte from it, then dropping a reference to the original.  (The V8 JavaScript engine [used to have this exact problem](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869).)

To avoid copying the underlying buffer, wrap your `bytes` in a [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) and slice that:

```
>>> bm = memoryview(b)
>>> qq = [bm[1:] for _ in range(50)]
```

Comment: That's CPython, right? If it's not specified, other implementations could do it differently.

Comment: From the [PyPy documentation](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html) about differences to CPython: *"equal strings may share their internal string data even if they are different objects—even a unicode string and its utf8-encoded bytes version are shared"* (talks about strings and equal, but I could imagine it shares data for bytes slices as well).

Comment: I did the same test under PyPy, it behaved largely identically.