# Asyncio BufferedProtocol doesn't do what it says in the documentation (doesn't avoid unnecessary copying)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#buffered-streaming-protocols):

*"BufferedProtocol implementations allow explicit manual allocation and control of the receive buffer. Event loops can then use the buffer provided by the protocol to avoid unnecessary data copies. This can result in noticeable performance improvement for protocols that receive big amounts of data. Sophisticated protocol implementations can significantly reduce the number of buffer allocations."*

Since my program reads large amounts of data from a socket connection and knows the amount of data it should receive; I was using a custom `BufferedProtocol` in the hopes of avoiding the data being copied around an unnecessary number of times, but an exception in my `get_buffer()` method led me to discover the ugly truth through the traceback:

**The buffer is not actually being used! instead the data is still copied, and is actually copied an extra time into the buffer I provided!.**

The `get_buffer()` and `buffer_updated()` methods are being called by `protocols._feed_data_to_buffered_proto()` which receives a `bytes` object and then feeds it into the buffer I provided, hence leading not to a reduction in the number of times the data is being copied but rather to the data being copied an extra time!.

After digging further into the guts of `asyncio` I find that the actual reading of data from the raw socket is actually being done using `socket.recv_into()`, but it is just not being received directly into the buffer I provided, instead it is later COPIED to the buffer I provided.

Is this correct? and if so WTF?!
or am I completely missing something obvious?

In case my understanding is correct, how do I fix it? what would it take to make asyncio actually avoid the extra copying by using my buffer directly in socket.recv_into()? can this be done without completely monkey-patching asyncio or rewriting the eventloop?

...

Regarding calls for a *"minimal reproducible example"*:

Raise an exception inside `BufferedProtocol.get_buffer()`, connected using `loop.create_connection()`, and the traceback will lead you to the following function inside `asyncio.protocols`:

```
def _feed_data_to_buffered_proto(proto, data):
    data_len = len(data)
    while data_len:
        buf = proto.get_buffer(data_len)
        buf_len = len(buf)
        if not buf_len:
            raise RuntimeError('get_buffer() returned an empty buffer')

        if buf_len >= data_len:
            buf[:data_len] = data
            proto.buffer_updated(data_len)
            return
        else:
            buf[:buf_len] = data[:buf_len]
            proto.buffer_updated(buf_len)
            data = data[buf_len:]
            data_len = len(data)
```

Not only is this function not avoiding unnecessary copying, in the worst case it is actually drastically increasing the number of times the data is being copied!

And no, `data` is not a `memoryview` as you might have hoped, it is a `bytes` object!

And in case you don't believe me that this creates many more unnecessary copy-operations please see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533054/does-slicing-a-bytes-object-create-a-whole-new-copy-of-data-in-python) regarding slicing `bytes` objects.

Comment: This will be a devil in the details situation... Can you provide a minimal working example of the problem?  (which will also help you solve it for yourself probably :) )

Comment: @BillHuneke I don't know what a "minimal working example" would be in this case, just look for yourself at what is actually calling BufferedProtocol.get_buffer() and you will find that it is a function which copies the data an extra time, that is not exactly something I can show through an example code.

Comment: I think you are right, that the line `data = data[buf_len:]` seems horribly inefficient.  I read your link about bytes slicing.  I tried it myself and watched allocation using valgrind. This test confirmed that `b = b'\1' * 100_000_000; b = b[1:]` does indeed allocate 200,000,000 bytes! I'm with you and this is not the first time the protocol code has disappointed me with its extra copying. Achieving zero copy does not appear to be a high priority in Python.  Maybe it's worth raising an issue ticket for that slicing line on github ... at least you might get a detailed explanation / rationale

Comment: @BillHuneke Yes agree, but the slicing line is actually the least of my concerns, from reading the documentation of `BufferedProtocol` I would have thought that the buffer I provide would be used to read directly from `socket.recv_into()` but instead it causes additional copies even if the slicing is not done, this to me is promising one thing and delivering the opposite, in other words "fools-gold", yellow and shiny but you'll waste your time digging it up...

Comment: Final comment here before I hop off the thread (I'm not sure I'm helping anything).  It seems to me (if we ignore the possible wastefulness of the slice operation) that we _might_ just be seeing the copy from kernel space up to user space.  The socket.recv_into is in C so maybe it's implemented as a call to recv_msg and then is calling _feed_data_into_buffered_proto using the pointer from iov_base.  If that were the case, I think the whole thing would be as close to zero copy as possible.  The copy that is done in _feed_data might just be a read from kernel space.  Probably wishful thinking...

Comment: *or am I completely missing something obvious?* - have you tried uvloop? Maybe the feature is provided to allow high-performance asyncio alternatives, such as [uvloop](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop), to make use of. asyncio might still use it in the future, but the documentation is intentionally written to make no guarantees.

Comment: @user4815162342 you have a point, sadly I can't use uvloop as I am on Windows, `pip install uvloop` failes with error: "uvloop does not support Windows at the moment". Also IMHO it should be more clearly stated in the asyncio docs that the current implementation of asyncio results in more data copies when using BufferedProtocol rather than fewer, since the reason for using it is to gain performance and at the moment it actually does the opposite, I consider the current documentation to be deceptive.

Comment: yes, the way to go seems to be through monkey-patching parts of the asyncio loop, and opening an issue against Python so that the "improvement" to actually do what is promised is fulfilled in a coming version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a lot of time reading through the asyncio code and related issues I think I can at least partially answer the question myself, although I would still appreciate anyone smarter than me chiming in and elaborating or correcting me if I'm wrong:

**The issue:** There is an issued with the `WSARecv()` Windows function used by `ProactorEventLoop` which can cause data loss, and for reasons I don't fully understand this has so far prevented the buffer returned by `get_buffer()` from being used directly when the `ProactorEventLoop` is used, hence the helper function `_feed_data_to_buffered_proto()` was created.

**Workaround:** If the event loop policy is instead set to `WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy` then the `BufferedProtocol` will behave as expected, I.e. the buffer returned by `get_buffer()` will be used directly in `recv_into()`, this however comes with some drawbacks (See [Platform Support](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-platforms.html#windows)), the `SelectorEventLoop` on Windows doesn't work with pipes or subprocesses!.

In my case since I'm not using pipes or subprocesses I solved it by adding the line: `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())`

So it seems that my issues is mainly with Windows and not with Python, what a surprise.

I still think it would be nice if this was mentioned in the docs so that I didn't have to find out myself the hard way.